# Cross-platform virtualenv automation

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

When using `virtualenv` on a UNIX-type system, you can do something like:

```
import sys, os
INTERP = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'env', 'bin', 'python')
if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
```

Similarly, when using it on Win32, you can do something like (but not actually):

```
import sys, os
INTERP = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'env', 'Scripts', 'python.exe'))
if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
```

I have a few questions about this pattern:

1. Is there a commonly-accepted means of doing this in a higher-level, more cross-platform way? (for example a library which can be pointed at the environment directory and have it query for/`execl` within the env's interpreter)
2. Is there an accepted pattern or at least reasonable approach for detecting if the environment hasn't been set up, and if so, setting it up (and doing a `pip install -r requirements.txt` et al)?

For context, I am trying to automate a Python 3-based build system which can occur on both Windows and OSX, and I would like to limit the number of platform-specific scripts that must be maintained and make the process more automation-friendly.

Comment: Ah, I just found out about Python3's [venv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv). Handy! I'll hopefully be able to answer my own question if someone else doesn't swoop in. :)

Comment: I have a workable solution that just needs a bit of testing. Unfortunately it was still very much a roll-your-own thing, but maybe I'll turn it into a library for people to use.